# Operations on List of Lists in Python - Scipy

Tags: scipy

I have been learning Python for a while now, but Scipy is something new I am experimenting with. So, I am stuck while implementing this:

I have this code,

```
data_mat = sparse.lil_matrix((500, 11000))

for i_i in range(0, totalcols):
    for j, data  in enumerate(data_mat):
        dw[i_i] = dw[i_i] + (data_mat[j, i_i] * (data_mat[j, totalcols] - prob[j]))
```

here,

```
dw[totalcols]  #is a list containing 11000 entries initialized to 0
```

what this code does is, it iterates through data_mat column wise and for each column, it gets the value row wise and does some calculations.

Example:

```
1,0,o,...........,1,0,0
0,1,1,...........,0,1,1
.......................
.......................
1,0,0,............0,0,0
```

A sparse matrix: data_mat of 500 X 11000 entries

I am able to achieve this, but, my program is taking way too long, like >10 mins to do the calculations.

Is there any better way to implement this??

Answer (score 0):

Use `numpy`. Used right, all the looping work would take place in the C-space (since numpy is a C extension), instead of the slow python-space looping, and in many cases would also make program shorter and more readable (although it's also very easy to write unreadable code with numpy).

`numpy` is an extremely powerful tool to have in you python toolbox, but expect a learning-curve.

Also:

1. `range(0, totalcols)` can simply be written as `range(totalcols)`.
2. `dw[i_i] = dw[i_i] + x` => `dw[i_i] += x`

Answer (score 0):

You need to vectorize the `dw` calculation.  Assuming that by `data_mat[j, totalcols]` you really mean, use the last column of `data_mat`, and `prob` is a `(500,1)` array (reshape if necessary), the following should work:

```
dw = (data_mat.multiply(data_mat[:,-1]-prob)).sum(axis=0)
```

I don't have realistic data to properly test it, but the data shapes appear to work.

I'd suggest getting it working with small dense (not-sparse) arrays first, and then small sparse ones before working on the large size.